# Install Windows 8.1 from Harddrive

Tags: linux, windows, windows-installation

I want to install Windows 8.1 from Harddrive. I don't have a CD-ROM, nor do I have a USB Capable of containing the Windows 8.1 ISO.

ATM, I'm running Linux on a USB Drive.

I've already set the harddrive to be MBR, and I've formatted a partition to be NTFS.

I have copied over all the files within the iso to the harddrive.

Now the only thing I'm having trouble with is making the windows installer to show up when booting into the harddrive. I've done this in the past, but I forget the final step to make it work.

Comment: How exactly are you "booting into the harddrive"? Do you mean you're simply accessing its contents via the Linux LiveUSB? To make Windows setup launch from the drive directly you'd need to set the partition as active and use `bootsect` from the install media to install the bootmgr, or possibly launch setup.exe via the command line (not the Linux one obviously). Can you honestly not access a big enough USB stick, even temporarily?